# Cleanest way to achieve a table in css, which one column is without explicit width (but wrap content), while the others with fixed width?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am having two tables that each takes up 50% of the screen, both looks like exactly the same. Each table contains three columns, The first column does not have explicit width, which takes up all the available space. The other two columns have fixed width no matter in what screen size. I want the content of the third column to be wrapped.

I tried to use a grid to construct a table like this:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto 80px 60px;
```

And I use a flex at the first column like this:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

This code works well if the content of the first column does not overflow, however the content will overflow if the content of the first column is too long (probably because flex-wrap would not work without explicit width, but **I need the first column (without explicit width), with its content wrapped, to fill the remaining space**).

I'm wondering, **if this should be achieved with a flex/table/grid, and how to handle the first column (is that even possible?) with css**.

Here is two images of the tables in different screen (first smaller screen, second larger screen)

[image: Tables in a smaller screen]

[image: Tables in a larger screen]

Comment: Maybe use [`flexgrow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp)?

Comment: I have already used flex-grow in the first column, it does the work of taking up the available space but it doesn't wrap the content

Comment: Did you try adding [`word-break: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher OMG that's it!! Apparently the grid tried to break the line with space but my content does not contain any space. So here word-wrap takes up the responsibility. Thank you!

Comment: No prob! `word-break` saved my project recently too haha it's a magical property ;)

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher don't you convert your comment to answer? So everyone can easily see the good approach.

Comment: @gazdagergo I could, but OP already added it as an answer so he / she can have the points haha

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher  Please leave an answer below so that I can give you the points you deserve, I'll delete my answer after that.  :)

Comment: Thanks @Andus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to "set whether line breaks appear wherever the text would otherwise overflow its content box."

Available [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Values):

- `normal` - "Use the default line break rule."
- `break-all` - "To prevent overflow, word breaks should be inserted between any two characters (excluding Chinese/Japanese/Korean text)."
- `keep-all` - "Word breaks should not be used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean (CJK) text. Non-CJK text behavior is the same as for `normal`."
- `break-word` - "To prevent overflow, normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line."

Note from docs:

> In contrast to `word-break: break-word` and `overflow-wrap: break-word`, `word-break: break-all` will create a break at the exact place where text would otherwise overflow its container (even if putting an entire word on its own line would negate the need for a break).